# jquery Datatable invalid JSON response 1 ,data is checked as valid json

Tags: python, json, datatables

I copied the response using chrome debug tools,and check it on http://www.bejson.com/ ,the result show it is a valid json. But on web page ,datatables shows warning it is not a valid json. Using the same backend code ,the pages shows well .I think the data has some problem when show on html or in Datatable processing.I use python to read the data from database and send to webpage after changing it to json code.If there a method ,how to solve it.
My data is:
[json data](http://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=4d6c63e6bef9b3cc34ce0f65c885561e)

Comment: Try working up a JSFidlle with what you've tried so far so we can look.

Answer (score 1):

Paste your JSON at [JSON Editor](http://jsoneditoronline.org/) and use the right arrow to test your JSON. It'll show you the errors, if any. In case you are still unable to find the error, save it online(jsoneditor provides option to save it online) and share the link here so that other's can help you. I'm afraid, the image you shared isn't much use.

**EDIT**: There are special characters like ▀▄▀▄▀▄ and ⚫⚫▶▶ in your JSON response. I'm assuming you are storing in DB just like these. While this is a valid JSON, what *exactly* is the error you are getting? Seems to me like the error must be encoding related. Before dumping to JSON, make sure you are encoding using UTF8 instead of Latin.

Comment: What is the encoding format you're using at DB level?